# Remove the event handler of the P element inside

Tags: jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I have an outside div, inside this is a lot of P elements and it binds an event handler:

```
$("#container").on("click","div",showNext)
```

and this click event binds successfully, but somehow all the elements inside are all bound to this event handler, how to remove?

See all the code here: [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/strangeline/cYKeX/)

All I want is to click the div and hide the current one and show the next one, but the problem is when I click on a p element it hides, neither...

So what did I miss? I am really new to Js.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".con").on("click",showNext)
 .children().on('click',function(e){e.stopPropagation();})
```

It prevents the click-event inside the children of .con from bubbling.

http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/KL4uw/

Comment: so when i add a event handler to a outer element, it will still effect the elements inside? this is a event bubbling?

Comment: No. Events are always dispatched to the target-element(the child-p in this case) and first trigger the event-listeners there(if any). Bubbling events(like click) then will also trigger the event  for any parent, up to the document-object(this is "bubbling")

Comment: hey,i have another problem with the auto run setInterval function,see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/strangeline/cYKeX/6/),why it disappear at all ,i only use the trigger method, why all this happened?